# sympy: sympify: `Piecewise` function instead of expected `diff` function

Tags: sympy

I have a quick question about the `sympify` function:

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import x, y, z
with sympy.evaluate(False):
    print(sympy.sympify("diff(x, x)"))
```

It results in `Piecewise((x, Eq(1, 0)), (1, Eq(1, 1)), (0, True))`.
I expected something like `diff` yet not a `Piecewise` function. Could you give me a hint why this happens? Is there a way to fix this to get a `diff` function instead of a `Piecewise` function? Is the input incorrect?

Comment: I get the expected result, which is 1. Which version of sympy are you using? `import sympy;print(sympy.__version__)`

Comment: sorry, I totally forgot to mention that I set evaluate to False. I'll edit it in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `diff` is not a symbolic function is has no unevaluated form:

```
In [1]: import sympy
   ...: from sympy.abc import x, y, z
   ...: with sympy.evaluate(False):
   ...:     print(sympy.sympify("diff(x, x)"))
   ...: 
Piecewise((x, Eq(1, 0)), (1, Eq(1, 1)), (0, True))

In [2]: import sympy
   ...: from sympy.abc import x, y, z
   ...: with sympy.evaluate(False):
   ...:     print(sympy.sympify("Derivative(x, x)"))
   ...: 
Derivative(x, x)
```

If you specifically want to be able to use `diff` rather than `Derivative` then you can use `parse_expr` and pass `diff` as a function in the locals dict:

```
In [5]: import sympy
   ...: from sympy.abc import x, y, z
   ...: with sympy.evaluate(False):
   ...:     print(sympy.parse_expr("diff(x, x)", local_dict={'diff':Derivative}))
   ...: 
   ...: 
Derivative(x, x)
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense now! Is there a command to check if a function is symbolic? I'll have a list of expression I need to sympify hence it would be nice to be able to check if the sympifying gives a plausible result.

Comment: You can check if it is a subclass of `Basic`.

Comment: Sorry, I need to ask again:
Do I need to check `issubclass(expr.func)` or `isinstance(expr.func)`? 
For `expr` being `sin`, `cos`, `exp` or `Piecewise` `issubclass` returns `True` for all, yet it should return `False` for `Piecewise`, right? `isinstance` returns `False` for all.

Comment: Piecewise is a symbolic function. You should use `isinstance` if you have an expression like `isinstance(exp(x), Basic)` or `issubclass` if you just have the function itself like `issubclass(exp, Basic)`.